# how to convert this syntax to normal php if else

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter form validation. To display form errors it uses this

```
 $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ?
     validation_errors() : 
     ($this->auth_lib->errors() ? 
         $this->auth_lib->errors() : 
         $this->session->flashdata('message')))
```

I don't understand this syntax. I think it is an if else statement. It is very hard to understand.

Can anyone please convert this to a normal if else statement?

Because now i am going to change the error message format:

```
$this->message->set_error($msg=array('Test 1','Test 2'));
$message=$this->message->get_message();
$this->data['message']=$message;
```

Anyone, please simplify the syntax. Thanks.

Comment: This is not from CI, but PHP itself: [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: this is why i hate ternary operators unless it's something very short.

Comment: Once you start using the ternary conditional operator, you learn to love it!  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a ? b : c == if (a) {b} else {c}

```
if (validation_errors())
{
    $this->data['message'] = validation_errors();
}
else if ($this->auth_lib->errors())
{
    $this->data['message'] = $this->auth_lib->errors();
}
else
{
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`$this->data['message'] =   (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->auth_lib->errors() ? $this->auth_lib->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')))`

is a multiple ternary operation equivalent to:

```
if ( validation_errors() )
   $this->data['message'] = validation_errors();
elseif ( $this->auth_lib->errors() )
   $this->data['message'] = $this->auth_lib->errors();
else
   $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is using [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  They can be very handy but also confusing at times if nesting several of them.  Here's the equivalent written without the ternary operators...

```
    if(validation_errors())
    {
        $this->data['message'] = validation_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        if($this->auth_lib->errors())
        {
            $this->data['message'] = $this->auth_lib->errors();
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
        }
    }
```